# Changing workflow in multilingual site works only for one language

Tags: workflow, plone, multilingual, linguaplone

I have a fresh Plone-4.1.5-site with Linguaplone-4.1.1 installed, two languages selected and the front-page translated into the other language.

When changing the workflow from simple_workflow to intranet_workflow via the controlpanel, and mapping old states to new ones, it occurs, that only objects of the current chosen language get the new mapping. Objects of the other language get the initial state of the new workflow.

Is it possible to do the mapping programatically to overcome this?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the control panel UI. LinguaPlone applies an automatic filter to catalog queries to include only items in the current language. The control panel presumably needs to override that to include all languages when it queries for items to re-map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it'll probably be simplest to just patch the code that remaps the workflows.

Open the `plone.app.workflow` egg (it's path will be listed in your `bin/instance` script), find the `plone/app/workflow/remap.py` file and edit it.

About halfway down you'll find the following line (line 79 in my copy):

```
for brain in portal_catalog(portal_type=type_ids):
```

and add `Language='all'` to that:

```
for brain in portal_catalog(portal_type=type_ids, Language='all'):
```

The alternative is copying that whole file into your own project, make that change locally, then calling it with:

```
statemap = {
    'oldstate1_id': 'newstate1_id',
    'oldstate2_id': 'newstate2_id'
}
chain_name = ('workflow_id',)  # tuple of wf ids (can be empty), or the string '(Default)'
portal_types = ('sequence', 'of', 'portal_types')

copiedremap.remap_workflow(portal, portal_types, chain_name, state_map)
```

The `remap_workflow` script then uses the *current* state of the object to find the new state it should have in the new target workflow(s) (it'll do this for each new workflow); if the old state is not listed in the map it'll use the initial state of the target workflow.

Comment: Thx so much, I own you a brewery! +1 for very nice answer with several possibilities to go. Should I file a bug-report, or is this recorded already? (I've seen you contributed for multiling-support in workflow-tool already, so I thought I'd just ask the source).

Comment: I didn't look for one, please do file one if you cannot find an existing bug report. Feel free to link to this post in the report when you do. :-)