# Plone and linguaplone: LanguageIndipendent = true & no update / reindex

Tags: plone, linguaplone

I've a plone4 website with Linguaplone 4.1.3 installed. I've write some simple AT content types to manage a "structure" of an organization.
The site is in production since 2013, with 4 languages.

This is the definition of a field in the custom AT "Structure" (called "struttura" in italian):

```
atapi.StringField('sitostruttura',
                             languageIndependent=True,
                             required=False,
                             validators = ('isURL',),
                             widget = atapi.StringWidget(
                             label = _(u'label_struttura_sito', default=u'Sito web'),
                                 )),
```

It works well with all the fileds but not with this one (the only LanguageIndipendent = true).
If I update the valued in this field is affected only the "original version" and not the versions in the other languages.

I've also tested creating a brand new content.
I've no errors, no warnings.

Comment: This quest resembles http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901739/changing-workflow-in-multilingual-site-works-only-for-one-language, maybe that can get you a hint, it's probably about reindexing the catalogue with "Language=all" set.

Comment: Mhmm, I don't agree with you. I've a "standard plone workflow".

Comment: Yeah right, I didn't mean your quest is related to workflows. The resemblence I see here, is that the changement applied only to the currently chosen, respectively canonical language. But it might be the wrong trace.

Comment: Actually I don't get what exactly you're asking for: With "I've write" you mean "I have to write" or "I have written"? What exactly have you changed ("the valued") and what exactly wouldn't work in comparison with the other non-independent fields? As I got it in first place, you want to have a field, of which the value entered via the UI, will apply to all the related items in the other languages, as well. Like it is the intention of lang-independent-fields. But maybe you ment s.th. different? Otherwise a comparison with the non-independent fields wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Oooh, this looks like the fit for you: http://lists.plone.org/pipermail/plone-product-developers/2009-March/008591.html Good luck!

Comment: WOW! thank's Ida this is a very good advice! The problem, then, is in the official linguaplone doc! :)

Comment: Glad it works! Feel free to post the solution as an answer (or even update the docs :O, our awesome doc-team will certainly welcome it), I'm sure it'll be of help for quite some more Plonistas out there. Have a great day, i

Comment: Ufff, no :( It does'nt work for me. The tip is right, cause linguaplone hasn't atapi, but it does'nt fix my problem. It's very annoying cause there is'nt any error or warning

Comment: The real import to make  is "try: from Products.LinguaPlone import public as atapi". Thank's Ida for your attention and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The import to make is

```
try:
    from Products.LinguaPlone import public as atapi
except ImportError:
    # No multilingual support
    from Products.Archetypes import atapi
```